# Migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5 in Java 11: Why am I getting 'Could not locate ordinal parameter [0], expecting one of [1, 2]'?

Tags: hibernate, java-11

I'm migrating hibernate4 to hibernate5, when I do an insert in a getNamedQuery I get the error Could not locate ordinal parameter [0], expecting one of [1, 2]

my DAO method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public List<SP_AccionUsuarioSolicitud> guardaBitacoras(JSONObject parametros) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SessionImpl sessionImpl = ((SessionImpl) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
    Connection connection = sessionImpl.connection();
    
    Query query = sessionImpl.getNamedQuery("setGuardaBitacoras");  
    query.setParameter(0, getClob(parametros.toString(),connection) ,ClobType.INSTANCE);
    
    List<SP_AccionUsuarioSolicitud> lista = query.list();
    return lista;
}
```

my DTO:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
                        name = "setGuardaBitacoras",
                        query = "{call PG_ACCION_USUARIO.SET_ACCION_BY_USUARIO(?,?)}",
                        resultClass = SP_AccionUsuarioSolicitud.class,                      
                        hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") }
                     )}
```

data that is sent:

```
            JSONObject parametros = new JSONObject();
            parametros.put("P_ES_LISTA", 0);
            parametros.put("P_FOLIO", dtoSolicitud == null ? 0 : dtoSolicitud.getId().getFolio());
            parametros.put("P_ANIO",  dtoSolicitud == null ? 0 : dtoSolicitud.getId().getAnio() );
            parametros.put("P_TIPO_SOLICITUD",  dtoSolicitud == null ? 0 : dtoSolicitud.getId().getTipoSolicitud());
            
            parametros.put("P_ID_GRUPO", usuarioLogueado.getIdGrupo());
            parametros.put("P_NOMBRE_USUARIO", usuarioLogueado.getUsername());
            
            parametros.put("P_ID_MODULO", idModulo);
            parametros.put("P_ID_ACCION", idModuloOpcion);
            parametros.put("P_ID_TIPO_OPERACION", idTipoOperacion);
            parametros.put("P_ID_TIPO_ACCION", idTipo);
```

I can't find the correct way to send the data, someone who has already gone through this

aid